# File storage in Heroku - alternatives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app in Heroku and love its simplicity, however, I need simple file storage for uploaded images (using file_column).  As I see it, my options are to migrate over to Slicehost or get the Heroku app working with Amazon S3 (I'm a bit perplexed by the S3 pricing scheme).  Are there other alternatives?

Comment: You can store the file as blob in a database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have multiple apps on Heroku using S3 for uploads.

I would recommend using the [attachment_fu](http://github.com/technoweenie/attachment_fu/tree/master) or [paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/tree/master) plugin over file_column. These plugins make it trivial to switch from the local file system to s3 (literally just ":storage => s3")

S3 has been reliable, fast, and cheap for me.

Answer (score 0):

We use dokkur.com

It has additional functionality - internal storage and databases